# Add command to history but keep old history

Tags: bash

I frequently start out my bash sessions by attaching to tmux, and have two machines I ssh in from, so detaching easily is also good. To make this easier, I added this line to my bashrc:

```
history -rs 'tmux attach -d'
```

However, this clears out all the past command history, so I can't CTRL-R to search for a recent command. This is suboptimal. Is there a way to get it added without clearing out old history?

Comment: Why do you need to add this to your bashrc? An alias would not be good enough?

Comment: An alias is another thing to memorize, and I basically never want this except when starting a shell.